# Font color not working

Tags: html, css

I tried so many things but the font color is not working. Could someone help?

```css
div ul{
  margin-left: 40%;
}
   
 .navigation li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10%;   
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
   <div class="navigation">
   <nav>
   <ul>
  <li><a href="#">culture</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cuisine</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">travel</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a selector `.navigation li a` and put the `color: #000;` inside it

Comment: Thank  you so much. But could you explain to me why doesn't work if I only use li??

Comment: The anchor link `a` is a child of `li`. <a> links are automatically styled by the browser to be blue. To style the <a> links in your `li` elements, you must specify it in CSS.

Comment: @TannerBabcock Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using hyperlinks, which have an inherent `color` property defined by the browser with greater **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** than your `.navigation li` selector.

Specifically, Chrome has the selector `a:-webkit-any-link`, which has a specificity of `1010`, while your selector has a specificity of `0010`.

In order to override this, simply put your `color` declaration on `.navigation li a`, targeting the `<a>` tags directly rather than relying on inheritance.

```css
div ul {
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.navigation li a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">culture</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">cuisine</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">travel</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)